# Unable to connect to sql database server

Tags: sql-server

Yesterday, I installed SQL Server 2008 on my PC. It was working perfectly, but now when I am trying to connect to the database engine, it generates this error:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is obstructing the connection string. Seeing how you are trying to connect would be useful. What is your connection string?

Comment: @mrjoltcola don't laugh, but by default I tried to drag the window on the screenshot; a sign I need more coffee

Comment: @nascant that suggests the server you are trying to connect to does not exist, is offline, or that you don't have access; since you are connecting from SSMS, this is not a c# / winforms question: until the database server is up and running, **it won't work from any programming framework**

Comment: @MarcGravell - ROFL too late, I laughed, loudly! - I almost did the same thing but wasn't going to mention it because it is 3am here.

Comment: @Nascent - Did you take the default instance name (MSSQLSERVER) or set your own? Is MIURZA the name of your SQL Server instance or the hostname of your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this.
[image: Example]

This will only work if you are trying to connect to the database on the same machine.  If you are writing software to connect to a remote database, you will need to work out what the connection string needs to be.  This website may help you. [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)